# Change object property (boolean) on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I need to change the property `IsOpen` to `false` from a `SupportTicket` with a button click in the ticket list and refresh the view so it only displays open tickets (`IsOpen = true`).

I tried with `public IActionResult Resolve(int number)` but doesn't work

**HomeController.cs:**

```
using Ev02.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Ev02.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public HomeController(IRepository repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(this._repository.TicketList());
        }

        public IActionResult Save(SupportTicket ticket)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this._repository.Add(ticket);
                ViewBag.Message = "Ticket guardado con éxito";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View("Index", ticket);
        }

        public IActionResult Closed()
        {
            return View(this._repository.TicketList());
        }

        public IActionResult New()
        {
            SupportTicket ticket = new SupportTicket();
            return View(ticket);
        }

        public IActionResult Resolve(int number)
        {
            SupportTicket ticket = this._repository.TicketGetByNumber(number);
            ticket.IsOpen = false;
            return View(ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
@model List<Ev02.Models.SupportTicket>
<h2>Tickets pendientes de resolución</h2>
<div class="col-2">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">N° de ticket</th>
                <th scope="col">Asunto</th>
                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                <th scope="col">Fecha de creación</th>
                <th scope="col">Acción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var ticket in Model)
            if (ticket.IsOpen)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@ticket.TicketNumber</td>
                        <td>@ticket.Subject</td>
                        <td>@ticket.Description</td>
                        <td>@ticket.CreatedDate</td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Resolve", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <td>
                                <button name="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Marcar como resuelto</button>
                            </td>
                        }
                        

                    
                    </tr>
                }
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried with `public IActionResult Resolve(int number)` but doesn't work

Comment: Based on what you've said and looking at your code, there could be multiple things causing the issue. What exactly isn't working? What happens instead of the desired behaviour?

Comment: Desired behaviour: `IsOpen` changes to `false` for the selected ticket, ticket list view refreshes and the modified ticket no longer appears on the list.



Actual behaviour: Execution halts and VisualStudio throws this error.

```System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

ticket was null.```

Comment: Have you confirmed the `number` is being passed properly to `Resolve(int number)` Action method? Either it isn't coming through properly, or your repository isn't retrieving the ticket properly using the `number`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't save the changes only update the entity.
For example, in EF, you need to invoke `_youDbContext.SaveChanges()` method after you update the entity.

So, you should invoke the `Repository.Save()` method after updating the flag and before returning the view.

P.S
The model is IEnumerable and you're passing a single ticket.